# Using a Cursor to compare Age

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I have a function that returns a @Return_table.

```
Samp      Age   CaseRole    Validate   Error
--------- ----- --------    --------   ------
SXXXXXX8  25    Mother      Old         
SXXXXXX7  36    Father      Old
SXXXXXX6   0    Child       Young
```

With this table I have to compare all of the "Young" ages against EVERY "Old" age to make sure data was entered correctly. I have most of the Cursor values setup, I just need some help with the actual compare part.

```
DECLARE AGEVALIDATE CURSOR for
  SELECT Age, Validate FROM @RETURN_Table
DECLARE @Error

OPEN AGEVALIDATE
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
  FETCH NEXT FROM AGEVALIDATE INTO @Error
    IF @@FETCH_Status <> 0 BREAK

UPDATE @RETURN_Table
```

this is where i am stuck

```
IF "Young" < "Old"
  THEN @Error = 'true' (or any value)
IF "Young" > "Old"
  THEN @Error = 'false' (or any value)
```

Thank you,

Comment: You know that cursors are a technique of last resort?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to compare? are you trying to very that all of the `OLD` people are older than any `YOUNG` people? If some why not `SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN Validate='Old' then age else null end) as 'YoungestOldPerson,Max(case when validate='Young' then age else null end) as OldestYoungPerson From my table`

Comment: Cursor have its place just not in this question!

Comment: I appreciate your insight @HLGEM. There are going to be times when I have multiple "Old" people and multiple "Young" people. Will your select statement work for that type of situation?